# expect() in .then() - jasmine unit testing, AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

Hello I have problem with .then() function while trying to implement jasmine unit testing.
Here is my code:

```
describe("getBuilding", function () {
  it("checks getBuilding", function () {
    var id_building = 4;
    LocalDB.getTestData();
    LocalDB.getBuilding(id_building).then(function (result) {
      expect(result.name).toMatch("Something");
    });
  });
});
```

In this case, the result variable has a right value in then() function, but expect just doesnt work here.  If i change "Something" to "something else" the tests will still succes, althought it should't.

I tried to solve it like this:

```
describe("getBuilding", function () {
  it("checks getBuilding", function () {
    var id_building = 4;
    LocalDB.getTestData();
    expect(LocalDB.getBuilding(id_building).name).toMatch("Something");
  });
});
```

or

```
describe("getBuilding", function () {
  it("checks getBuilding", function () {
    var finalResult;
    var id_building = 4;
    LocalDB.getTestData();
    LocalDB.getBuilding(id_building).then(function (result) {
      finalResult=result.name;
    });
    expect(finalResult).toMatch("Something");
  });
});
```

But in both cases, the value that's being matched is undefined. Can anyone give some advice pls?

Comment: Your second approach has a problem. `.then()` is executed only after the request is completed, whereas your `expect()`  is executed right after the AJAX call is made. Which means that it is still `undefined`.  To solve this. You can use a Promise to wait until the request is finished to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to :http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

Jasmine has support for async methods. Essentially your issue is your asserting before your async call has responded. Therefore it has no data and your assert fails.

So according to the above link you could do something like (not tested, i haven't used jasmine so cannot be certain im following the link correctly either. Hopefully you can understand better than i).

```
describe("getBuilding", function () {
  it("checks getBuilding", function () {
    var id_building = 4;
    LocalDB.getBuilding(id_building).then(function (result) {
      expect(result.name).toMatch("Something");
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: @StephanBijzitter As apposed to what just a link and a brief explanation? There are many times you need to post pseudo code to better explain something when unable to actually physically test it yourself. If i was incorrect (it seemed i was half way there), fair enough. But posting pseudo code is perfectly fine as long as it is clearly marked as such.

Comment: This one actually work after updating to Jasmine 2.0

Answer (score 2):

Your 'then()' is probably not being run at all - since the promise is resolved asynchronously, you need to either ensure that the promises are resolved before exiting the test or use jasmine async to ensure that jasmine waits for the async method to resolve before moving on to the next test.

In unit tests with promises, often you need to manually notify the angularjs lifecycle that it's time for promises to be resolved.

Try bringing in the `$rootScope` dependency and adding a call to `$rootScope.$digest()` at the end of your test.

```
describe("getBuilding", function () {
  it("checks getBuilding", function () {
    var id_building = 4;
    LocalDB.getTestData();
    LocalDB.getBuilding(id_building).then(function (result) {
      expect(result.name).toMatch("Something");
    });
    $rootScope.$digest();
  });
});
```

If that doesn't work by itself, you may also need to use Jasmine Async

```
describe("getBuilding", function () {
  it("checks getBuilding", function (done) {
    var id_building = 4;
    LocalDB.getTestData();
    LocalDB.getBuilding(id_building).then(function (result) {
      expect(result.name).toMatch("Something");
      done();
    }, function(){
      done.fail('The promise was rejected');
    });
    $rootScope.$digest();
  });
});
```

The jasmine async way using `done` is a better test, because it will fail if the promise is rejected. The first would silently pass if the promise was rejected. However, if you know that this particular promise will always resolve, the first way may be good enough for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try to return the promise.

```
return LocalDB.getBuilding(id_building)
    .then(function (result) {
       expect(result.name).toMatch("Something");
    });
```

Comment: Tried, but didnt help. The test will still succes even if I change "Something".

Comment: Sorry, just one more comment. Do LocalDB.getTestData() return a promise? Because in that case you should do that call and then(LocalDB.getBuilding(id_building))

Comment: Yes it does return a promise, but I already solved this problem with done()